# /extractor/backoff_sampler.cc:24:18: error: ‘round’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: compiling, c++, make

I am trying to build [cdec](https://github.com/redpony/cdec) on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (running in VirtualBox on Windows 10). Please note that I am not at all an experienced Linux power-user.

I executed the commands given in the aforementioned cdec repo:

```
cmake .
make -j4
make test
./tests/run-system-tests.pl
```

However, during `make` I got an error to which I couldn't find the trace. Disabling multithreads and setting VERBOSE (`make VERBOSE=1`), I got the following trace:

```
[ 79%] Building CXX object extractor/CMakeFiles/extractor.dir/backoff_sampler.cc.o
cd /tmp/cdec/build/extractor && /usr/bin/c++  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DKENLM_MAX_ORDER=6 -I/tmp/cdec -I/tmp/cdec/build -I/usr/include/eigen3 -I/tmp/cdec/extractor/../utils -I/tmp/cdec/extractor -I/tmp/cdec/extractor/features  -Wall -std=c++11 -O3 -g -fopenmp   -o CMakeFiles/extractor.dir/backoff_sampler.cc.o -c /tmp/cdec/extractor/backoff_sampler.cc
/tmp/cdec/extractor/backoff_sampler.cc: In member function ‘virtual extractor::PhraseLocation extractor::BackoffSampler::Sample(const extractor::PhraseLocation&, const std::unordered_set<int>&) const’:
/tmp/cdec/extractor/backoff_sampler.cc:24:18: error: ‘round’ was not declared in this scope
     int sample = round(i);
                  ^~~~~
/tmp/cdec/extractor/backoff_sampler.cc:24:18: note: suggested alternative: ‘rand’
     int sample = round(i);
                  ^~~~~
                  rand
extractor/CMakeFiles/extractor.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'extractor/CMakeFiles/extractor.dir/backoff_sampler.cc.o' failed
```

I am not at all a C++ developer, but I would assume that the source code was written for a compiler that has a native `round()` function (or something like that?), but that on my set-up this is not the case.

I am not sure which information could be useful, so here's a guess:

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0
- GNU Make 4.1

I will probably have to do changes in the source code I assume, but I don't know what to change to or replace by what. Any indicators are welcome.

Note: bug [was reported to the developer](https://github.com/redpony/cdec/issues/99).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that your delete the program folder and install a new one from the archive. Your stopped at 79% of the installation and have the error "extractor.dir / backoff_sampler", to get around it you need to re-create (your start from the end) the 'cdec' folder in a new unzipped program. (i used Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on hdd).

```
# apt install cmake git build-essential libboost-dev libboost-regex-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-serialization-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-test-dev libboost-thread-dev libeigen3-dev libbz2-dev liblzma-dev flex libgtest-dev

# git clone https://github.com/redpony/cdec.git

# cd cdec 

# apt update

# apt install golang-github-cenkalti-backoff-dev

# cmake .

# make -j4

# reboot

# cd cdec

# cmake .

# make -j4
```